# Using Twitter on iOS 5 +: via Tag in Posts, existing Twitter-App

Tags: iphone, twitter

I have a twitter-app "myname" and an iOS 5 + -App "myname". With my iOS App I'd like to post tweets.

Questions (how is the "via" tag in tweets set):

1. Can I use my twitter-app as a reference, and if - how is this configured?
2. If I want to use my iOS-App instead, how is the "via myname" set and how can I configure the URL it refers to (when the link is cklicked). Do I have to set a certain URL in iTunes-Connect?

In https://dev.twitter.com/issues/39 is stated:

> [Ensure] That your application's name as registered with Apple ... is not duplicative of an application name in Twitter's database.

1. Does this mean, if I already have a twitter-app "myname" and an iOS App whith the same name, I cannot use "myname" in the via-tag?
2. What happens, if somebody registeres a twitter-account that has the same name as my iOS App? Is "via myname" forbidden after that and sombody can prevent me from using my app name on twitter that way?

Answer (score 5):

Well, after submitting a support Ticket to Apple and 3-times begging them to give me more precise answers - thats all I got from them:

1. **Can I use my twitter-app as a reference, and if - how is this configured?** Answer: Not possible using the Twitter SDK. Remark from me: You can do that if you use third party solutions like [DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController)
2. **If I want to use my iOS-App instead, how is the "via myname" set and how can I configure the URL it refers to (when the link is cklicked). Do I have to set a certain URL in iTunes-Connect?** Answer: It's the Support URL in iTunes Connect

For the other both questions Apple Support rejected answering my questions and told me to contact Twitter Support.